# C# MSWord iterop align one column of a table

Tags: c#, ms-word, alignment

I want to align one column to the center and the only way that I found was this, I think it isn’t good and I am looking for an elegant solution.

```
foreach(MSWord.Cell celda in table.Columns[1].Cells){
    if(celda.ColumnIndex == 1){
         celda.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = MSWord.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
    }
}
```

As you can see it aligns cell by cell, I was wondering if there is a way where you can align as a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to work with a Word table column "in a block" (perform an action in one step) is to *select* the column, then apply the command to the `Selection`. This is one of the few times in Word where it makes sense to use a `Selection` object...

```
Word.Cell celda = table.Cell(1, 1);
celda.Column.Select();
celda.Application.Selection..ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
      MSWord.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```